# What is the "distance from the nearest integer"? (is that a kind of norm?)

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, notation

We define the function
$$\Vert \cdot \Vert: \mathbb{R} \to \left[0,\frac 1 2\right]$$
as
$$\Vert x \Vert = \min\big(x - \lfloor x\rfloor, 1 - (x - \lfloor x \rfloor)\big)$$
for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
I proved that the triangular inequality is true (the proof is quite simple, but a bit long because I deal with five different sub cases, I have written in italian so I do not post it, if you want I can write it).
We know that $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is not a norm nor a semi norm because it is not true that, for $\lambda, x \in \mathbb{R}$ it holds
$$\Vert\lambda x\Vert = \vert\lambda\vert\cdot\Vert x\Vert.$$
Using the triangular inequality it follows that it is true the following:
$$\Vert\lambda x\Vert \leq \vert\lambda\vert\cdot\Vert x\Vert.$$

I use the symbol "$\Vert$" to denote $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ because it is a norm in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ but I think that this notation is a bit weird. My question is: is that function a kind of norm in $\mathbb{R}$ (I know only norms and semi norms, maybe there are other types of norm)? I would like to know this because otherwise I would have better to change the way I denote that function, using the standard notation for function, such as $f(\cdot)$ instead of $\Vert\cdot\Vert$.

Comment: What do you mean it's a norma in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$? This isn't a vector space.

Comment: You are right I came here for editing! The question is now motivated more than before: is there any good reason for using $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ notation instead of $f(\cdot)$ apart from legibility?

Comment: I made that mistake because (I think) that in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is true that
1. $\Vert x \Vert = 0 \implies x = 0$;
2. $\Vert x + y\Vert \leq \Vert x \Vert + \Vert y \Vert$;
3. $\Vert \lambda x + \mathbb{Z} \Vert = \vert \lambda \vert \cdot \Vert x + \mathbb{Z} \Vert$, when $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x + \mathbb{Z} \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.